# Passing props from class component in react + typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am new to typescript and am wondering how to pass the prop from my class component to a parent class.

My child class looks like this:

```
import React from "react";

type Props = {
startTimeInSeconds: number;
}

type State = {
timeRemainingInSeconds: number;
}


export default class Child extends React.Component<Props, State>{
    private timer: any;

constructor(props: Props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    timeRemainingInSeconds: props.startTimeInSeconds
  };
}

decrementTimeRemaining = () => {
  if (this.state.timeRemainingInSeconds > 0) {
    this.setState({
      timeRemainingInSeconds: this.state.timeRemainingInSeconds - 1
    });
  } else {
    clearInterval(this.timer!);
  }
};

componentDidMount() {
  this.timer = setInterval(() => {
    this.decrementTimeRemaining();
  }, 1000);
}

render() {
  return (
    <div className="countdown-timer">
      <div className="countdown-timer__circle">
        <svg>
          <circle
            r="24"
            cx="26"
            cy="26"
            style={{
              animation: `countdown-animation ${this.props
                .startTimeInSeconds}s linear`
            }}
          />
        </svg>
      </div>
      <div className="countdown-timer__text">
        {this.state.timeRemainingInSeconds}s
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
}
```

I wanted to call this child component in my parent component but I don't get how it is working.
I tried to call the child within the parent with

`<Child startTimeInSeconds = { this.startTimeInSeconds } />`

but it throws an error.

A (simplified) parent component looks like this:

```
import '../css/App.css';
import * as React from "react";
import Child from "./ChildComponent"

function App(props) {
  return (
    <>
    <div>
        <Child startTimeInSeconds = { this.startTimeInSeconds } />
    </div>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: What is the error that it throws?

Comment: Would be nice to see a parent of Child Component, since I suspect you pass the prop in the wrong way. Child component seems fine

Comment: Please share parente component code and error details

Comment: you can;t use `this` in functional components.

Comment: @hussain.codes: Is it just  `<Child startTimeInSeconds = {startTimeInSeconds } />` then?

Comment: @ExplosionPills: The error is 
_TypeError: Cannot read property 'startTimeInSeconds' of undefined_

Comment: Well, looking at the parent code, you never defined this.startTimeInSeconds anywhere

Comment: @Terminat: I added `type Props = {startTimeInSeconds: number}` and changed the input of the function to `function App(Props: Props) { return (...)}` Now I get to see the component, but the states are not changing. I am calling the child with `<Child startTimeInSeconds = {Props.startTimeInSeconds}/>`

Comment: That's fine. You have to defined `startTimeInSeconds` in App component.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Child component is fine, but you are passing incorrect props to it.

In `App` component you need to define `startTimeInSeconds` variable>

You parent component should look like this -

```js
import '../css/App.css';
import * as React from "react";
import Child from "./ChildComponent"

function App(props) {
  const startTimeInSeconds = 0; //or any number
  return (
    <>
    <div>
        <Child startTimeInSeconds = { startTimeInSeconds } />
    </div>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```